# Evaluating $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{2^k} \frac1{e^{t/{2^k}} + 1} $

Tags: riemann-zeta-function, zeta-functions

If I arrive to calculate the sum $\displaystyle  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  \frac k{2^k} \frac{1}{\large e^{\frac t{2^k}} + 1} $ I think I can give a close form to the values $\zeta(1+\frac {2ip\pi}{\ln2})$ $(p\in \mathbb Z^*)$ in terms of $\Gamma(1+\frac {2ip\pi}{\ln2})$ and $\Gamma(\frac {2ip\pi}{\ln2})$ only.

***Note*** :
We can already see
$$ \frac1{2^k} \frac{1}{\large e^{\frac t{2^k}} + 1} = \frac1{2^k} \frac{1}{\large e^{\frac t{2^k}} - 1} -  \frac1{2^{k-1}} \frac{1}{\large e^{\frac t{2^{k-1}}} - 1} $$
so
$$  \sum_{k=1}^{n}  \frac1{2^k} \frac{1}{\large e^{\frac t{2^k}} + 1} = 
\frac1{2^n} \frac{1}{\large e^{\frac t{2^n}} -1} -  \frac{1}{\large e^t-1 } $$
and
$$  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  \frac1{2^k} \frac{1}{\large e^{\frac t{2^k}} + 1} = 
\frac1{t}  -  \frac{1}{\large e^t-1 } $$

Comment: Notice that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2^k}\frac{1}{e^{It/2^k}+1} = \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} -  I\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\tan\frac{t}{2^{k+1}}$, and $\displaystyle -\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\tan\frac{t}{2^{k+1}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \ln\cos\frac{t}{2^{k+1}}$. So, the telescoping used for summation is essentially the formula for the product of cosines: $$\cos\frac{t}{2^n}\cos\frac{t}{2^{n-1}}\cdots\cos\frac{t}{2} = \frac{\sin t}{2^n\sin\frac{t}{2^n}}.$$